# How can I configure a sharepoint job to run every 50 days

Tags: development

With built-in sharepoint schedules, I can configure a job to be run hourly, daily, weekly and monthly but how can I configure it to run (for example) every 50 or 70 days?

Do I need to write my own SPSchedule derived class?

Comment: belongs on sharepoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is your custom job, you can make it run daily, register in say farm property the last time it ran and skip it for the next 49 days (just exit right away after checking the property)